# select count from both tables using join in postgesql

Tags: postgresql

how to find number of records in both table using join.
i have two tables table1 and table2 with same structure.

table1

| id | item |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 1 | C |
| 2 | A |
| 2 | B |

table2

| id | item |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 2 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 2 | C |
| 2 | D |

Output should be  like this.

| id | table1.itemcount | table2.itemcount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | 4 |

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT id, (
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 AS table1_2 WHERE table1_2.id=table1.id
) AS "table1.itemcount", (
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2 AS table2_2 WHERE table2_2.id=table1.id
) AS "table2.itemcount"
FROM table1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that each `id` is guaranteed to exist in both tables, the following would work

```
select 
    t1.id, 
    count(distinct t1.item) t1count, 
    count(distinct t2.item) t2count 
from t1 
join t2 on t1.id = t2.id
group by 1;
```

But if that is not guaranteed then we'll have to use full outer join to get unique ids from both tables

```
select 
    coalesce(t1.id, t2.id) id, 
    count(distinct t1.item) t1count, 
    count(distinct t2.item) t2count 
from t1 
full outer join t2 on t1.id = t2.id
group by 1;
```

We're using `coalesce` here as well for `id` because if it only exists in t2, `t1.id` would result in null.

@DeeStark's answer also works if ids are guaranteed to be in both tables but it's quite inefficient because count is essentially run twice for every distinct id in the table. Here's the [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/49myZgF9JWGMCLbX3LLjiQ/1) where you can test out different approaches. I've prefixed each query with explain which shows the cost

Hope this helps

Comment: Glad it helped. Would request you to choose this as the answer so that the thread is resolved (and I gain some reputation points )